# Ctrl+Space not working in Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (64bit) and the key combination Ctrl+Space is not working with my JIdea. I'm trying to use it for code completion in the IDE.

There are no system shortcuts assigned to that. And JIdea keymap shows this shortcut for Code->Completion->Basic but I cannot even re-assign it to Ctrl+space. (I CAN change it to any other shortcut)

Basically Ctrl+Space is a no-op in JIdea, but if I set the system shortcut to some other program, it works...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does [Smart Type Code Completion](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/smart-type-code-completion-completing-code-based-on-type-information.html) (Ctrl+Shift+Space) work?

Comment: Then I'd say that you do have a conflict with some system shortcut.

Comment: Theres nothing on the system shortcuts for ctrl+space. But if I assign something for Ctrl+Space, that works. (in system shortcuts)
(Ex: Shortcuts-> Launchers-> Launch Help Browser = Ctrl+Space)

Comment: This guy had similar problems with NetBeans: http://jetcracker.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/ctrl-space-doesnt-work-ubuntu/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If [Smart Type Code Completion](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/smart-type-code-completion-completing-code-based-on-type-information.html) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) works while the [Basic Code Completion](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/basic-code-completion-completing-names-and-keywords.html) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) does not I'd say that there ***is*** a problem with the key combination because some other program is using it.

Here's a [link to another user](http://jetcracker.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/ctrl-space-doesnt-work-ubuntu/) who had problems with it for NetBeans and the solution is:

> The key combination didn’t work because some other program used it. To fix this I used gconf-editor.
>
> 1. Open gconf-editor.
> 2. Choose desktop -> ibus -> general -> hotkey.
> 3. Open trigger parameter.
> 4. Remove Ctrl+Space key combination from the list and press OK.

Comment: It's not recommended to use ibus because of [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23472).

Comment: @CrazyCoder ibus has already been installed on the system when I install the OS itself. (12.04 LTS)

Answer (score 7):

Try "sudo apt-get purge ibus" and reboot.

Get rid of ibus altogether. It does absolutely nothing for most of us. JIdea is not the only program that's being affected. Eclipse, emacs, even Minecraft for goodness.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the only solution I had for making other shortcuts in NetBeans working. Not sure if it is a good solution though ;).

Comment: Solved the CTRL+SPACE problem in Intellij IDEA on Mint 17 Qiana.

Comment: Solved for me too with intellij IDEA on xubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thank you very much. I had no idea it's safe to uninstall ibus.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem in KDE (kubuntu) ubuntu 14.04.  The issue was that there is an ibus Preferences that I was able to open via a keyboard icon in the notification tray.  There was a Ctrl Keyboard shortcut to move to the "Next input method" which I deleted.  Now it works again!  Very frustrating to find!